# Alternating and convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)$ be a decreasing sequence with $a_n \to 0$. Find $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^ka_{n+k}$$
I guess that the limit is $0$ and I tried to use the $\epsilon$ proof, i.e. to find a number $n_{\epsilon}$ such that $|a_n-a_{n+1}+...+(-1)^na_{2n}|<\epsilon, \forall n \geq n_{\epsilon}$, using the fact that $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, but I didn't get anything... I don't know how to use the fact that $(a_n)$ is decreasing

Comment: Are you familiar with Leibniz's alternating series test?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to apply it here

Comment: Shroud. Robert's hint, S_n is convergent,  hence S_n is a Cauchy sequence. Helps?

Comment: Yes, it is very clear now! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$|a_n-a_{n+1}+\dots+(-1)^{n}a_{2n}|=|S_{2n}-S_{n-1}|$$
where $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^ka_{k}$. Moreover, by [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), the sequence $(S_n)_n$ converges to a real number $L$.